# Automatic variable selection for imputation modelling

Tags: machine-learning, feature-selection, random-forest, data-imputation, elastic-net

I have a large data set with 10.000 observations and 1.000 variables. Some of my variables have missings and need to be imputed. R Packages like `mice` suggest to use all available variables as imputation model. However, with 1.000 variables this is not possible due to computational problems. Since it would be a huge workload and very difficult to select the best predictors manually, my plan is to use automatic variable selection methods such as lasso, elastic net, and/or random forest. The procedure would look like follows:

*Step 1) Apply automatic selection methods to find an appropriate imputation model for each variable.*

*Step 2) Impute based on these models.*

For me, this procedure seems to be very intuitive and there is a lot of literature about automatic selection methods available. However, I am struggling to find any research literature about the application of automatic selection in the context of imputation modelling. I am therefore wondering if there are any flaws in my procedure.

**Question 1: Are there any problems with my suggested procedure?**

**Question 2: Is there any research literature about this topic available?**